# initializing an array without using a for loop

Tags: arrays, c

If I want to create a vector of `size` components and I want all components to be `1`, one way to do this is, of course, to use a `for` loop in this way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size=100;
    int array[size];
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        array[j]=1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't look like the way programmers would do it.
How can I do this vectorially, that is, without changing one element at a time?

Comment: It really depends. What is the initial value you want all elements to have? If it's zero then initialize it on definition. Otherwise there's `memset` to set the individual *bytes* (not elements). But no matter what you do, ultimately there will always be a loop *somewhere*, even if it's not explicitly in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there are no alternatives to the loop in standard C.

If `gcc` is an option you can use [Designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) to initialize a range of elements to the same value:

```
int array[] = {[0 ... 99] = 1};
```

Comment: I noticed that this will not work in case I want to provide the size as a parameter, rather than writing the numerical value "99" explicitly. Is there a way to make it work in that case?

Comment: You can use `int array[100] = {[0 ... (sizeof array / sizeof array[0]) - 1] = 1};`

Comment: Can this method be used if you don't know size until runtime?

Comment: @SimonGoater do you mean with a Variable-Length array, no, you can not: _error: variable-sized object may not be initialized_